# Why does GetMember(string) return an array of MemberInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was working with reflection and came across the error:

> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type

because I thought that `Type.GetMember(string)` would only return one `MemberInfo`, but [it doesn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmember?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetMember_System_String_).

I'm curious for the reasoning why `Type.GetMember(string)` returns `MemberInfo[]`. The other reflection methods like `Type.GetProperty()` and `Type.GetMethod()` return their respective `PropetyInfo` and `MethodInfo` objects.

What is the purpose of having `Type.GetMember()` return an array of `MemberInfo[]` when the other reflection methods do not?

Comment: [C# method overloading](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/method-oveloading-and-overriding-C-Sharp/) allows you define multiple methods with the same name with different call signatures. So there could be more than one member that matches, hence the return type has to be an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're getting a member by name, and you might have overloads of a method with the same name, although they are different members.

For more information, you might want to visit [Method signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods#method-signatures)

Answer (score 1):

While the notes about overloading are true, this seems more a case of “for historic reasons”.

`GetMethod(string)` is defined as returning either the sole match, or throwing `AmbiguousMatchException` if there are multiple overloads.
`GetMember(string)` simply always returns all matches.

I suppose the argument would be that if you don’t know what kind of member you’re asking for, you also don’t know how many matches there are, so it’s better to return all of them.

Calling the method `GetMembers` would have been more consistent, but that’s not something that’s easily changed.